# MS SQL pagination and grouping

Tags: sql-server, pagination, grouping, row-number

I need help, because I'm struggling on how to page through and limiting that each page just show one process at a time. I have tried so many things and my brain got fried.  Help........
So if the `@PageNum = 1 and @Pagesize = 10` and if the first process has 7 rows; first page will show 7 rows of the first process (exactly what I want).
Now if the user chooses `@PageNum = 2 and @Pagesize is 10` and the second process has 11.  I want it to show the top 10 of this next process.

Currently it's showing only the last 8 of the second process.

I simplified the SQL to remove business information and then just to show the list of what I'm dealing with:

```
/*
notes:
Parameters passed in are @PageNum and  @PageSize
@PageNum is which page they user goes to 
@PageSize is the max number of rows to show
*/

DECLARE @StartRow int, @EndRow int
SET @StartRow = (@PageNum -1) * @PageSize +1;
SET @EndRow = @PageNum * @PageSize;

WITH ProcessestoPageThru AS
(Select  Name, 
       ProcessId,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Name, ProcessId, ) as RowNo,
       COUNT(Name) OVER() as RowCnt
from a whole bunch of tables
where a whole bunch of criteria
)

  SELECT  * INTO #tmp_ProcessestoPageThru 
  From ProcessestoPageThru 
  Where RowNo BETWEEN @StartRow AND @EndRow

  Declare @ProcessID int
  --Get the top ProcessID, We are only going to display one Process at a     time
  Select Top 1 @ProcessID = ProcessId
  From #tmp_ProcessestoPageThru 

  Select *
  from #tmp_ProcessestoPageThru
  Where ProcessId = @ProcessId
```

Please see example attached:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFQ9o.jpg)
[image]

Comment: what version of sql server?

Comment: SQL Server 2008 r2

Comment: Much better jus to show the sample date and Expected result.

Comment: Add sample data and expected result to fully understand your question.

Comment: I think what you're trying to do is use the ProcessId as a Page Number, where ProcessId is not a sequence starting from 1.  The code you have wont do that.  What you need to do is create a temp table with a sequential number against each ProcessId, then select from that temp table based on the sequence number to get the Nth ProcessId, and return that.  Is that what you are trying to get at?  If so I will write a more detailed answer.

Comment: You are doing it back to front. Firstly determine your ProcessID then do your RowNumber with filter by ProcessID applied to source table. No temp table needed.

Comment: when pageindex=1, Pagesize=10, and if firt process has 7 rows then page one will show 7 process.That means page=1 will show only 7 records and it won't touch second process records.similarly you hv to explain few scenario with example.

Comment: @user5151179 It sound like that.  I'm going to post an example.

Comment: @KumarHarsh - yes... the second page should be the first row of the and should be 10 rows in all, the third page should be the last row of the second process and is 1 row (because the second process has 11).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with other sample data.

If it is slow with real data then let me know with details.

i) you are only passing parameter like @Pageinde,@Pagesize apart from other search criteria.

ii)TotalPage is the number of pages that you get and have to ppolate your page accirdingly.forget the old calculation.

iii) rowcnt is not required.

```
declare @Pageindex int=1
declare @Pagesize int=10



declare @t table(processid int, rowcnt int)
insert into @t values(1,345),(1,345),(1,345),(1,345),(1,345),(1,345),(1,345)
,(1,345),(1,345),(1,345),(1,345),(1,345)
,(2,345),(2,345),(2,345),(2,345),(2,345),(2,345),(2,345),(2,345)
,(2,345),(2,345),(2,345),(3,345),(3,345)


;with CTE as
(
select * 
,DENSE_RANK()over(order by processid) rownum
--,ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by processid order by processid) rownum1
,ROW_NUMBER()over(order by processid) rownum2
from @t
)
,CTE1 AS(
select *,
case when (rownum2/cast(@Pagesize as FLOAT))=1 then (rownum2/@Pagesize )
ELSE  (rownum2/@Pagesize )+rownum END PageIndex

from cte c
)
select processid,rownum2    
,(select max(PageIndex) from cte1) TotalPage
from cte1
where PageIndex=@Pageindex
```

Comment: Had to work through it to understand what was going on, but this will work!!  Thanks so much.  I couldn't figure it out and had to ditch the pagination for the project.  Now that you gave me this I'm reopening it up and having it done correctly :-)

Comment: @DonnaLynn , don't forget to report about performance issue,in fact you can share your real query if neccessary.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to do a `PARTITION BY` on `ProcessId` to display the results by that column value. Here is the code that may help you to do that.

```
;WITH ProcessestoPageThru AS
(
Select Name, 
       ProcessId,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY ProcessId ORDER BY Name, ProcessId ) as RowNo,
       COUNT(Name) OVER() as RowCnt
FROM processes
)
SELECT  Name,
        ProcessId,
        RowNo,
        RowCnt
From ProcessestoPageThru 
Where RowNo BETWEEN @StartRow AND @EndRow
AND ProcessId = @ProcessID
```

Comment: Thanks...I will try it

Comment: @Donna Lynn, If that works for you, consider mark my post as answer.

Comment: It doesn't work for what I'm doing.  Thank you any way.